# Custom view from xib added to controller via Interface builder - keep autolayout constraints and resize by them

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, xib

I've created custom UIView subclass that should work as popup dialog. I want to be very reusable so I created my subclass in own xib file and set auto layout constraints there. In interface builder it looks like this:

[image: PhotoDetailInfoDialog.xib]

It should resize height by text in UITextView. This is my custom subclass:

```
class PhotoDetailInfoDialog: UIView {

  var view: UIView!

  let nibName: String = "PhotoDetailInfoDialog"

  @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var mainTextView: UITextView!
  @IBOutlet weak var bottomButton: UIButton!

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
  }

  func setup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()

    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]

    addSubview(view)
  }

  func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    return view
  }
}
```

In Interface builder for controller where I want to use it I added view and set class to my PhotoDetailInfoDialog.

[image: Controller in interface builder with PhotoDetailInfoDialog]

(After taking screenshot I added width constraint).
How to set it right that in controller height of custom view would be recalculate dynamically by constraints in custom xib (and maybe without error in interface builder)?

In my case I set in code many lines of text for UITextView but it shows as follows:
[image: How it looks like now when run]

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can not set the `view`'s class to a customView which already has `.xib`  which in your `storyboard`.

Because in the `xib`, it has already create the `interface` for the `PhotoDetailInfoDialog`.

If you drag a `view` to `storyboard` and set the class to the `PhotoDetailInfoDialog`, there will come `issue`. and you can run your project again, it will crash with `EX_BAD_ACCESS`.

I advice you to take your `PhotoDetailInfoDialog` program in your `vc`'s code. and that maybe more flexible to show `dialog` with condition or action.